# RN - Map directly from state syntax

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to map an array from state - but confused re the correct syntax - can anyone please advise where i'm going wrong:

This is what I have at the mo:

```
      newsStorys = () => {
    return (
      {this.state.newsFeed.map((a) => {

        <View style={ModalStyles.newsArticle}>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDate}>{a.date}</Text>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsTitle}>{a.title}</Text>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDesc}>
          {a.story}
          </Text>
        </View>

    }
  }
    );
  };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had a play and a good dig around the web and found the syntax answer:  (Thanks to Bruno for the Key and pointers).

```
newsStorys = () => {
   
    return this.state.newsFeed.map((value, index) => {
      return (
        <View style={ModalStyles.newsArticle} key={index}>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDate}>{value.date}</Text>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsTitle}>{value.title}</Text>
          <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDesc}>{value.story}</Text>
        </View>
      );
    });
  };
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have provided a complete example in point 2. Great job!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if that is the whole code of your component, but I can see three things.

1. If `newsFeed` is not initialized when component first render (let's say it is undefined yet), then `newsFeed.map()`will throw an exception.
2. You are not returning anything from map call. you should write something like this:

```js
     newsStorys = () => {
      if (!this.state.newsFeed) return null;
      return this.state.newsFeed.map((a) => ({ // <--- note the parentheses here, you don't have it
          <View style={ModalStyles.newsArticle}>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDate}>{a.date}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsTitle}>{a.title}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDesc}>
              {a.story}
            </Text>
          </View>
       });
     );
   };
```

If you want to avoid the parentheses, then you need to explicitly return something, like this:

```js
    this.state.newsFeed.map((a) => {
       return (
          <View style={ModalStyles.newsArticle}>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDate}>{a.date}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsTitle}>{a.title}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDesc}>
              {a.story}
            </Text>
          </View>
       );
    });
```

It is possible that you need an extra view to wrap the list of views returned by map.

3. Also you need to provide a unique key to each view, so React can keep track on them.

```js
   <View style={ModalStyles.newsArticle} key={'nome unique value'}>
     ...
   </View>
```

Finally I think it would be better using a `FlatList` instead of `map`.

Cheers!

Comment: Thanks very much @Bruno - Newsfeed state is populated with an array of stories on initialisation.  I tried your code - but still get a syntax error on the return line in your first example - 2nd example doesn't error - but also doesn't work!  It displays nothing (despite a console log displaying the states array content

Comment: Also thanks for the key note - I forgot that - its now aded

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
newsStorys = () => (
    this.state.newsFeed.map(({ date, story, title }, index) =>
        <View key={`news-${index}`} style={ModalStyles.newsArticle}>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDate}>{date}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsTitle}>{title}</Text>
            <Text style={ModalStyles.newsDesc}>{story}</Text>
        </View>
    ));
```